# Second Timer with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, timer

i have a jquery function like the below, and display resualt in span but when reload page this span hide and show for for a while .
i want that not hide and show Is there a way to do this?
Because I use it as a timer.!!

```
<span id="timer"></span>

<script>

       var counter = 61;
       var x = setInterval(function () {

           counter = counter-1;
           $('#timer').html(counter);

       },1000);

   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your timer from `60sec` instead of `61`.

```js
var counter = 60;
$('#timer').html(counter);
var x = setInterval(function () {
  counter = counter-1;
  $('#timer').html(counter);
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Initialise your `span` with counter before `setInterval`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Initially your timer span is empty.

```js
var counter = 61;
$('#timer').html(counter); // add this line
var x = setInterval(function () {
  counter = counter-1;
  $('#timer').html(counter);
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are setting the html after one sec. Before setInterval is triggered, there is nothing present in the span.

This is what you can do

```js
var counter = 61;
const timer = $("#timer");
timer.html(counter);
var x = setInterval(function () {
  counter = counter-1;
  timer.html(counter);
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="timer"></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/f1kytyhz/